# Why do Arabic characters behave as separate characters when styling single Arabic character in ANDROID?

Tags: android, nativescript

I am new on this. But I did follow an example to render coloured letters:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ZaGBJr

```
<Label class="h1">
        <FormattedString>
            <Span text="صُ" color="#990000" class="quran"></Span>
            <Span text="مٌّۢ" color="#ffcc00" class="quran"></Span>
        </FormattedString>
</Label>
```

But the results are different between android and iOS. Where did i do wrong?

iOS(Perfect):

[image: iOS]

Android(separated characters):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yo just need to add [ZWJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) (zero width joiner `\u200D`) in between. See below example with hTML:

```html
<h1>
        <FormattedString>
        <Span style="color:#990000">صُ</Span><Span  style="color:#ffcc00">مٌّۢ</Span><br><br>
            <Span style="color:#990000" >صُ&#x200d;</Span><Span style="color:#ffcc00">مٌّۢ</Span>
        </FormattedString>
</h1>
```